# Rounding up hh:mm:ss.00 to hh:mm:ss

Tags: time, rounding, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to round up time (hh:mm:ss.00) in OpenOffice Calc, but to no success.

For example, I am trying to round up the following time to HH:MM:SS

```
01:41:32.69 -> 01:41:33
01:45:59.20 -> 01:46:00
01:31:48.62 -> 01:31:49
```

I tried the following quickfix method

=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)>50,MROUND(A1,1/(24*60*1000)),MROUND(A1,1/(24*60*60)))

No matter what happens, the IF statement returns the Then_value instead of the Otherwise_value

fyi - IF(Test, Then_value, Otherwise_value).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried the following one, and it works:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1;2)>50;MROUND(A1;1/(24*60*1000));MROUND(A1;1/(24*60*60)))
```

I replaced every comma with a semicolon.

Comment: Hmm.. not working for me. Openoffice Calc (Linux) is changing everything back to commas. Strange. a bug someplace? I'll investigate and give a response.

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, I think it doesn't make a difference whether is it a "," or ";". But thanks for replying.

Comment: You're right, it also works with commas. Did you format the destination cell as "time"? Which version of OO are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If it really is OO Calc I suggest:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1;2)*1>50;MROUND(A1;1/(24*60*1000));MROUND(A1;1/(24*60*60)))
```

String functions like RIGHT always return Text format, and any Text is always greater than every number.